# Increment an integer pointer and assign the value of the incremented pointer to another variable in C++

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code in Microsoft Visual Studio:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int *p;
    int val;
    p = &i; 
    *p = 101; 
    val = *(p + 2);
    cout << val << endl; 
    cout << i << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

In the line `val = *(p + 2)`, since `*(p + 2)` returns the value of the second integer after the one to which p points, and p currently points to the integer 101, I expected val to be of value 101+4×2=109.

When I executed the code in Visual Studio, the output showed the value of variable val was instead a random garbage value. Why was this so?

Comment: And what exactly did you expect to happen with this? Which value did you expect to get, and why, exactly? What value did you expect for "the second integer after the one to which p points", and where do you think it comes from?

Comment: Did you mean: `val = *p + 2`? In case `p` is a pointer to an array, you could simply use `p[2]` (what you're doing now), but here, you don't have an array, so I assume you want the value at `p` and add `2`.

Comment: @BlayerBond I actually want the value of the second integer after the one at p.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: "I actually want the value of the second integer after the one at p" - Why would you think there's a valid integer there for you to read?

Comment: @YuanLinTech -- `In the line val = *(p + 2), since *(p + 2) returns the value of the second integer` -- There is no guarantee the variables are laid out in memory in some sort of "linear' fashion.

Comment: The only guarantee here is that the program is invalid because it is doing undefined behavior.  Therefore, any behavior that is observed is allowed.  It may even appear to do what you expect.  (On my machine, it crashes.)

Comment: @Eljay well that's interesting, cause undefined behavior can be purple for all we know just saying... :)

Comment: @YunfeiChen • I like purple.  Minnesota Vikings purple.  I live walking distance to Prince's Paisley Park studio, another purple.  Purple is grand!

Comment: @Eljay although it is a bit weird, if I try to compile this program on my MacBook, it gives me warning: value of val is abitary.....

Comment: @YunfeiChen • `export CXXWARN="-Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -pedantic -fsanitize=undefined,null,address,bounds,bool,enum"` and `alias c17='/usr/bin/clang++ ${CXXWARN} -std=c++17'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it all wrong.

p points to i. It means that p stores the address of i.  Which adress it is, is unpredictable.  It may be 123456.  We only know that at this adress, the number 101 is written.

*(p+2) is the integer which is stored in memory at 2 positions after i.  For instance, if i has address 123456, and integer is 4 bytes, then *(p+2) is an integer at address 123464 (which is 123456+2*4).  What is stored here, and why, is unpredictable.

Just like if you live at Flying Macaron Monster Rd. 12345, I have no idea who lives at Flying Macaron Monster Rd. 12346 or Flying Macaron Monster Rd. 12347.

Answer (score 3):

> p currently points to the integer 101, I expected val to be of value 101+4×2=109.

Your expectation is ill-founded.

> since *(p + 2) returns the value of the second integer after the one to which p points

This would be correct if `p` pointed to an element of an array. But it doesn't point to an element of an array, and because it doesn't point to an element of an array, it also follows that there is no "second integer after the one which p points".

> Why was this so?

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`val = *(p + 2);` does not points to value of some second integer after `i=101`. `p` pointer has its own memory address in the memory and when you write `p + 2` you went ahead two memory address, equal to the size of your pointer size in memory times 2. So `val` gets value at (p+2) address, which is garbage. Check out `cout << &p` and `cout << &(p+2)`.  They are different and one points to `i` and other holds garbage value.